# How do I update my Mac to use the latest version of Python?

Tags: python

I downloaded the latest version of python, but when I go into the terminal and type the following Command:

```
Python --version
```

It returns Python 2.7.10

I have looked at tons of online tutorials and cannot figure out how to get my Mac to actually use the latest version of python that I installed.

Comment: Try `python3 --version`

Comment: macOS ships with Python 3.7.4 (in Catalina, anyway; earlier versions may have an earlier versions of Python 3). It's installed as `python3`, though.

Comment: To use your custom install, you'll need to update your PATH to include the directory where that version lives before `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into installing Homebrew.

It is a great package manager for macOS and does let you install new versions of python using its `brew install` command.

You can look at the installation details here: https://docs.brew.sh/Installation

Answer (score 0):

```
brew install python3
python3 --version
```

Comment: You'll need to follow the instructions on this site first ```https://tecadmin.net/install-homebrew-macos/```